# How to add a CSS stylesheet in FXML

Tags: css, javafx, stylesheet, fxml, scenebuilder

I'd like to link a css file to my application.
In my fxml file I use this:

```
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@../stylesheet1.css" />
  </stylesheets>
```

...and I can see a styled preview when I open the fxml file in scenebuilder. But when I try to run the application I get an error:

*java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ../stylesheet1.css*

So I tested it this way:

```
<stylesheets>
    <String fx:value="stylesheet1.css" />
</stylesheets>
```

and now it's other way round - the application starts and applies the css, but I don't see the preview in scenebuilder. The error message:

*"The file stylesheet1.css doesn't exist. Resource stylesheet1.css not found."*

So how do I attach the css file properly?

---

Well, although my question wasn't answered why exactly it doesn't work the above way, I found a solution that works for me. In my FXML I have just the line

```
<?scenebuilder-stylesheet ../stylesheet1.css?>
```

so Scenebuilder works with that css.
And in my main class I set the stylesheet programmatically:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
String css = this.getClass().getResource("../stylesheet1.css").toExternalForm(); 
scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
```

Comment: Could it be that you declared to different locations for the CSS file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The css file is located in the src folder and the fxml in the src/main package. I tried different Strings but it didn't work. But I found some kind of workaround. I update my post.

Comment: For me using absolue url worked. Like: <URL value="@/fxmlexample/Login.bss" />

Answer (score 14):

What I found usable and working solution to include `css` file in `fxml`
is add     `stylesheets="@app/cssfilename.css"` to the parent node of the `fxml` file just as for stack pane

```
<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.fxml.SettingsController" stylesheets="@app/cssfilepath.css">

......
.....
.....
</StackPane>
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a solution that works in the development environment, in Scene Builder and in a packaged JAR.

The folder structure:

[image]

Main.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            AnchorPane rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/application.css").toExternalForm());

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

RootLayout.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.view.RootLayoutController">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="sunButton" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="88.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSunButtonClick" styleClass="sun-button" stylesheets="@../css/toolbar.css" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

RootLayoutController.java:

```
package application.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class RootLayoutController {


    @FXML
    Button sunButton;

    @FXML
    public void handleSunButtonClick() {
        System.out.println( "Button clicked");
    }
}
```

toolbar.css:

```
.sun-button {
  -fx-graphic: url('./icons/sun.png');
}
```

application.css:

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color:lightgray;
}
```

sun.png:

[image]

This works in both the development environment and when you package the JAR (choose "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" in Eclipse).

Screenshot (just a button with an icon loaded via css)

[image]

Comment: scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/application.css").toExternalForm());

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to do it programmatically, you can do it by separating code and resources. I have a Maven project structure like this, but this is not a requirement.

```
src/main/java/${packageName}
    MainWindow.fxml
src/main/resources/${packageName}
    stylesheet1.css
```

Now you can use the stylesheet in the `.fxml`

```
stylesheets="@stylesheet1.css"
```

or by using the stylesheets tag as you did.

There may be a warning in `SceneBuilder` but it works.