# JavaFX - Loading stylesheet for custom control

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

In JavaFX you can load a stylesheet for a scene using something like this

```
scene.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("/css/background.css").toExternalForm());
```

If i create a custom control, like below, can i load a stylesheet for that control to use from within that control. rather than the scene?

Here is a basic control

```
public class EventListPane extends VBox {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Event> listView;

    public EventListPane() {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/EventListPane.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);

        // Can i load the stylesheet for this control somewhere here??

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.Log("Error loading eventListPane");
        }  

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Check out my post in [How to add a CSS stylesheet in FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975897/how-to-add-a-css-stylesheet-in-fxml), especially the toolbar.css which in my case is loaded via the fxml.

*And before someone complains again that I shouldn't reference content: Do you really want me to copy/paste my solutions multiple times? I think I've posted the referenced comment already 4 times here ... it's always a different question (stylesheet image not loaded, image in devenv loaded but not in jar, etc), so not a duplicate, but the same solution.*

Comment: duplicate (c&p is just as bad as linking) answer means duplicate question :-) The way to handle duplicate questions is to close them ... The other way round: if you think the question is different enough, you can point out the exact difference and add an excerpt from your other answer tailored exactly to that difference.