# Reference of CSS file in FXML

Tags: css, fxml

can we give css reference for whole fxml file.
AS in XML we give (XML-stylesheet href="name.css")
So,can it is possible for FXML file or else i have to give stylesheets=@name.css file for every  label,button etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a CSS stylesheet in FXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975897/how-to-add-a-css-stylesheet-in-fxml)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful reference for CSS file in FXML

Check these bellow links:

**How to add a CSS stylesheet in FXML:**
[How to add a CSS stylesheet in FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975897/how-to-add-a-css-stylesheet-in-fxml)

**FX CSS Reference Guide:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

**How to add style to XML:**
https://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html

**How do I style an XML file with CSS?:**
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-style-an-xml-file-with-css.html

Also, you can research that with a simple google search. :)

Thank you.