# Applying CSS to stack charts in FXML

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, linechart

I am trying to implement a set of stacked charts in FXML similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788117/stacking-charts-in-javafx). I'm fairly inexperienced and couldn't find whole examples of setting up CSS in FXML Controller. Trying to adapt code myself has resulted in either the `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception, `loadStylesheetUnPrivileged' message, or both, and the code either doesn't run, or runs without any changes to the CSS. SceneBuilder is able to show a transparent preview, but it doesn't work when running the program.

FXML:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="graphpane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Graph1Controller">
<children>
  <StackPane fx:id="stackpane" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
     <children>
        <LineChart fx:id="M1chart" legendVisible="false" prefHeight="388.0" prefWidth="573.0" style=".chart-plot-background{-fx-background-color: transparent;} .default-color0.chart-series-line{-fx-stroke: #006564;}" stylesheets="@..css/M1chart.css" title="Recent Lap Times">
          <xAxis>
            <NumberAxis fx:id="M1xAxis" forceZeroInRange="false" minorTickVisible="false" side="BOTTOM" tickLabelsVisible="false" tickMarkVisible="false" />
          </xAxis>
          <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis fx:id="M1yAxis" autoRanging="false" label="Laptime (s)" side="LEFT" upperBound="240.0" />
          </yAxis>
        </LineChart>
        <LineChart fx:id="M2chart" legendVisible="false" prefHeight="388.0" prefWidth="573.0" style=".chart-plot-background{-fx-background-color: transparent;} .default-color0.chart-series-line{-fx-stroke: #FFCE44;}" stylesheets="@..css/M2chart.css" title="Recent Lap Times">
           <xAxis>
              <NumberAxis fx:id="M2xAxis" forceZeroInRange="false" minorTickVisible="false" side="BOTTOM" tickLabelsVisible="false" tickMarkVisible="false" />
           </xAxis>
           <yAxis>
              <NumberAxis fx:id="M2yAxis" autoRanging="false" label="Laptime (s)" side="LEFT" upperBound="240.0" />
           </yAxis>
        </LineChart>
        <LineChart fx:id="L1chart" legendVisible="false" prefHeight="388.0" prefWidth="573.0" style=".chart-plot-background{-fx-background-color: transparent;} .default-color0.chart-series-line{-fx-stroke: #832C40;}" stylesheets="@..css/L1chart.css" title="Recent Lap Times">
           <xAxis>
              <NumberAxis fx:id="L1xAxis" forceZeroInRange="false" minorTickVisible="false" side="BOTTOM" tickLabelsVisible="false" tickMarkVisible="false" />
           </xAxis>
           <yAxis>
              <NumberAxis fx:id="L1yAxis" autoRanging="false" label="Laptime (s)" side="LEFT" upperBound="240.0" />
           </yAxis>
        </LineChart>
     </children>
  </StackPane>
</children>   
</AnchorPane>
```

There are 3 CSS sheets I want to load, each of which is in the same folder (css), the folder placed in the same directory as the Java source files, and each is structured similar to this:

CSS:

```
.chart-plot-background{
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.default-color0.chart-series-line{
-fx-stroke: #832C40;
}
```

In the main class I've tried to follow [Roland's answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975897/how-to-add-a-css-stylesheet-in-fxml/28123426) but it doesn't seem to work.

Main:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

//First FXML Controller code omitted

//Second FXML Controller code starts here
Stage stage2 = new Stage();
FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader();
String fxmlDocPath2 = "(filepath)\\Graph1.fxml"; //actual filepath replaced with placeholder for this post
FileInputStream fxmlStream2 = new FileInputStream(fxmlDocPath2);
AnchorPane root2 = (AnchorPane) loader2.load(fxmlStream2);
Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2);
scene2.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/M1chart.css").toExternalForm());
scene2.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/M2chart.css").toExternalForm());
scene2.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/L1chart.css").toExternalForm());
stage2.setScene(scene2);
stage2.setTitle("TEST");
stage2.setX(primaryStage.getX() + 550);
stage2.setY(primaryStage.getY());
stage2.show();
//Second FXML Controller code ends
}
```

Running this code gives me the errors below:

```
null/..css/M1chart.css
null/..css/M2chart.css
null/..css/L1chart.css
Oct 10, 2018 10:45:22 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "..css/M1chart.css" not found.
Oct 10, 2018 10:45:22 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "..css/M2chart.css" not found.
Oct 10, 2018 10:45:22 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "..css/L1chart.css" not found.
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.Core.start(Core.java:71)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Core
```

I'm not sure what I've missed to cause the null to appear in from on the css path and the code to fail, could someone please help?

Comment: Where exactly is `css` folder located? You're using relative path, is `css` folder in the same package as your main class (package `application`, judging from the  stack trace)? If `css` folder is in the classpath root instead, you should use absolute path: `getClass().getResource("/css/M1chart.css")`.

Comment: The CSS path is in the same folder as the main class of the application, yes. If I change to use the absolute path `getClass().getResource("/css/M1chart.css")`, do I need to change anything in the FXML file? Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are 3 CSS sheets I want to load, each of which is in the same folder (css), the folder placed in the same directory as the Java source files

You should move your css/fxml files into a separate resource folder - some build tools won't even copy your resources to output directory if they are in the same folder as source files.

Let's say that your project structure is this:

```
YourApplicationRoot
 |--res   //resource root
 |  |-fxml
 |  | |-Main.fxml
 |  |-css
 |    |-styles.css
 |--src   //source root
    |-application
      |-Core.java //main class is here
```

Firstly, don't use inline styles in FXML (`style="some rules here"`) - it's hard to maintain.

Next, you don't really need 3 separate CSS files, you can put all you css styles into one file (`styles.css`) and use custom style classes to separate them:

```
/* These styles will only be applied to a chart with class `m1chart` */ 
.m1chart .chart-plot-background{
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.m1chart .default-color0.chart-series-line{
  -fx-stroke: red;
}

/* These styles will only be applied to a chart with class `m2chart` */
.m2chart .chart-plot-background{
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.m2chart .default-color0.chart-series-line{
  -fx-stroke: blue;
}

/* These styles will only be applied to a chart with class `l1chart` */
.l1chart .chart-plot-background{
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.l1chart .default-color0.chart-series-line{
  -fx-stroke: green;
}
```

Now, you have two ways to apply css to your application - from `fxml` and from code:

To apply `styles.css` from `fxml`, just add `stylesheets` attribute to root node and add `styleClass` attribute to each `LineChart` you want to style:

```
/* Main.fxml, irrelevant parts are omitted */
<AnchorPane stylesheets="@../css/styles.css">
   ...
   <LineChart styleClass="m1chart">
      ...
   </LineChart>
   <LineChart styleClass="m2chart">
      ...
   </LineChart>
   <LineChart styleClass="l1chart">
      ...
   </LineChart> 
   ...   
</AnchorPane>
```

Don't forget to remove `style` and `stylesheets` attributes from `LineChart` nodes.

To apply `styles.css` directly from code (note that your css styles won't be visible in SceneBuilder if you're using this method):

```
//in Core.java start() method
yourScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/styles.css").toExternalForm());

//in your fxml controller
M1chart.getStyleClass().add("m1chart");
M2chart.getStyleClass().add("m2chart");
L1chart.getStyleClass().add("l1chart");
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with my code, I've implemented all the changes you suggested, but it still doesn't work. Trying to apply css by code `scene2.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/styles.css").toExternalForm());` still results in a `NullPointerException` at that line, and trying `FXML` I still get the following console output similar to before: `null/../css/styles.css
Oct 11, 2018 10:46:48 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "../css/styles.css" not found.` Is there a way to directly specify the directory directly?

Comment: I tried a few things including moving the workspace folder, messing with the build path configuration to add the `/res` folder, and reloading the project, and it works now in the Java code for reasons I'm not entirely certain about (though the FXML method still doesn't work for some reason) I'm happy to progress though, and I can't thank you enough for your detailed explanation!

Comment: I forgot to tell you, resource folder must be marked as resource root in your IDE (if it already isn't), or it won't be copied to output folder (and you'll get `NullPointerException`). I don't know why `FXML` method doesn't work (SceneBuilder doesn't always update preview when adding `CSS` without making any other changes to `fxml` document, but it should always work when app is executed) - you should post a link to your source, if possible.