# Why does Inteliij Idea interprets @ symbol as null in files path

Tags: java, javafx, builder, scene

i have javafx application and i work with fmxl file. In scene builder after setting up my css file i got

```
stylesheets="@../../resources/style.css"
```

but if i run application with inteliij i got an error

```
null/../../resources/style.css
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

it's not only about including css file to fxml, but also if i try to set img path in ImageView happens the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a CSS stylesheet in FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975897/how-to-add-a-css-stylesheet-in-fxml)

Comment: Resources are not file paths; they are URLs which are relative to the root of the built application.  Try `stylesheets="@style.css"`.

Comment: What is the role of the `@` symbol at the beginning of the path? (Sorry if this comment does not fit here, but I like to know.)

Comment: @VinceEmigh I think it describes fine how to include .css file properly. Different issue, but same logic for solution.

Comment: To clarify this, he recieves null for /../../resources/style.css. @ before the name of the .css file indicates that the stylesheet is in the same folder as the FXML file ( For his situation I highly doubt about it however ). @NoelNemeth